# Html: Set Heading into the center

Tags: html, css

I start to learn HTML and on my website in the middle of the top there should be a heading in the center. In the left top corner, there is a picture.
If I want to set the heading with `align="center";` into the middle I can only set it into the middle between the right end of the picture and the right end of the Display...

I hope it's understandable and someone can help me!

The code is:

```
    <div style="float:left; width=600px; height=152px;">
        <img src="bilder/logo.jpg" height="54px" width="214px"    hspace="0" vspace="0"/>
    </div>
    <p>
        <h1 align="center" style="margin-top:15px; margin-bottom:20px;"><u>Peter Möhle</u></h1>         
    </p>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Azt1U.png)

It should look like the Picture at the Bottom but this was made mith margin-left and isnt a fixed Position if i use another browser or display

Comment: Your CSS and HTML syntax are incorrect. Also, you used a lot of deprecated attributes in HTML.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated your snippet as you are using deprecated tags. Happy to hear and clear your doubts, if you have any.

Ref: [W3 CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp), [W3 HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp)

```css
.nav {
  width: 100%;
}

.logo-holder {
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
}

.logo {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-text {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="logo-holder">
    <img class="logo" src="bilder/logo.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="nav-text">
    <h1>Peter Möhle</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer but if i try it the Picture has his normal size and the heading is on the left side under the picture

Comment: @J.Doe I'm unable to understand you mate. Can you add a screenshot or image of what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I've used padding to the left now using relative value

```
<div style="float:left; width=600px; height=152px;">
    <img src="bilder/logo.jpg" height="54px" width="214px"  hspace="0" vspace="0"/>
    </div>
    <p>
       <h1 style="margin-top:15px; margin-bottom:20px; padding-left: 50% "><u>Peter Möhle</u></h1>         
    </p>
```

Comment: It is nearly the solution of my Problem but the Heading is now in the Center of the Right end of the Picture and the Right and of the Display. Is there a opportunity to place the Heading with something like: (align=Center) - (the half width of the Picture) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `text-align: center;` to centre text, but as mentioned in the comments you are using some deprecated tags.

`<h1 style="margin-top: 15px; margin-bottom: 20px; text-align: center; text-decoration: underline;">Peter Möhle</h1>`

It's even better to remove the `style` attribute and create a css file to put the styles in.

**CSS**

```
h1 {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

I'd also change the div markup to

```
<div style="float: left; width: 600px; height: 152px;">
    <img src="bilder/logo.jpg" style="height: 54px; width: 214px;">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer and that you Show me how to make the style better with CSS, but it isnt a solution for my Problem it Shows nearly the same.